# How to find this ODE solution $u''-2\alpha xu'+\beta u=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out a substitution to change that ODE to seems like Hermite Equation: $$u''-2xu'+nu=0,$$ com $n$ a non-negative integer. The difference between both is the constant $\alpha$.

Comment: My understanding is that with $\alpha=1$ a whole number for $n$ is needed to get those special elementary function solutions you seem to know.  I am not sure how to solve the general case but it looks like it would involve Bessel functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-2\alpha x\frac{du}{dx}+\beta u=0$$
HINT : The change of variable 
$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}X\quad\text{and}\quad \lambda=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$$
Transforms the equation into :
$$\frac{d^2u}{dX^2}-2X\frac{du}{dX}+\lambda u=0\:,$$
which is solved in terms of confluent hypergeometric function and/or Hermite polynomial dependig on particular $\lambda$. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html